# Алгоритм решения олимпиадной задачи. Не понимаю назначения пары строк

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, олимпиада

Требуется найти количество пар элементов, произведение которых кратно 113, и расстояние между элементами больше 5. Ниже приведен код.  Прозведение кратно 113, если один из множителей кратен 113. Будем считывать элементы и считать количество кратных 113 чисел, при этом рассматривая каждый элемент как правый член пары.

Тут мне понятно назначение строк `if a_ % 113 == 0 : count += i - distance` , а вот почему в противном случае выполняется это мне не понятно `else: count += n113`.

Код:

```
distance = 5 # Расстояние между элементами
a = [] # храненеие последних distance значенй
n113 = 0 # Кол-во элементов %113 ==0
cnt = 0
a_ = 0 # Очередное значение
N = int(input())
for i in range(distance): # Ввод первых 5 элементов
    a[i] = int(input())
count = 0 # Число искомых пар
n113 = 0 # Кол-во чисел, делящихся на 113
for i in range(distance +1, N):
    if a[0] % 113 == 0 :
        n113+=1
    a_ = int(input())

    if a_ % 113 == 0 :
        count += i - distance

    else:
        count += n113

    for j in range(0, distance-1):#сдвигаем элементы влево
        a[j] = a[j+1]
    a[s] = a_
print(count)
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> при этом рассматривая каждый элемент как правый член пары

Нет, текущий элемент, т.е. `a_`, рассматривается как второй элемент пары.

Если текущий элемент сам кратен 113, то в паре с ним все более ранние элементы на расстоянии `> distance`. Т.е. всего `i - distance` элементов.
А если не кратен, то только те из них, что сами кратны 113.

Вот это значение (количество всех чисел кратных 113 слева от текущего элемента на расстоянии `> distance`) и поддерживается в переменной `n113` с помощью очереди `a`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Нет слов, как я благодарен!

Comment: @korzh Только имейте в виду, что решение не рабочее. Алгоритм-то правильный, но код с ошибками.